# Exporting only selected items in My Places to another KML File in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: kml, google-earth-pro

It seems that when I right click and export from my places in google earth pro, it will export the entire kml instead of the selected or checked items within it.

How can I just simply export the checked items to another kml?

Even when I import the KML into arcmap, there is no indication of what was selected etc. IF that was the case, I could do a query.

Answer (score 2):

When you save out a KML file from Earth, it should save the current "visibility" settings for each feature. There's no way to save only the currently visible (checked on) items.  When opening the KML in ArcGIS, I believe it ignores the visibility settings of the features, so you'll lose that info.

Two ways I can think of to do what you want... 1.) Make a copy (copy/paste) of the KML in Earth, and then quickly go through and delete the features you don't want to export before saving out as KML. Or 2.) Export the full KML with visibility settings and use some other scripting or regex tool to go through and remove all Placemarks/Features that have visibility=0.