# How do I export a KML for one layer in a KML file that has multiple layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, kml, export

I'm accessing the Index plots for Ordnance Survey map sheets, provided as a KML by the Charles Close Society here: https://www.charlesclosesociety.org/indexes (scroll to the bottom of the page for the KML download).

And loading the file to Google Earth, where it is possible to view all the Index plots overlayed in one big jigsaw, or view one at a time.

I would like to export one of the layers only, import to ArcGIS 10.+ and convert from KML. Although I'm viewing only one layer when I try to export, I'm still getting all the data in the exported file. Rather than the single layer I need.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Please [Edit] your question to provide more information on the steps you took to attempt the conversion.

Comment: Please, explain how this Q is different from: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241564/exporting-only-selected-items-in-my-places-to-another-kml-file-in-google-earth-p. Tks.

Comment: Thanks for flagging that. It might have been the same question, but I didn't really understand the answer so couldn't tell.

Answer (score 1):

To save out just one part of the larger KML in Google Earth Pro:

1. Go to the Places panel on the left.
2. Expand the folder structure until you get to the part you want.
3. Right-click on the folder or individual item that you want to export/save.
4. In the right-click menu choose "Save Place As...".

That will allow you to save just one folder or item out of the original KML.  The visibility settings (check marks) will not change what is or isn't exported.